# Google App Engine - connect debugger on production

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a production issue with a GAE application. The problem seems to be related only to some users.

Is there a possibility to connect the local debugger to the prod version ? I'd like to avoid to have to copy the prod data to the dev server.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This situation has improved as of a few days ago with the intoduction of **Google Cloud Debugger**

> Earlier this week at Google Cloud Platform Live, we launched the beta release of Cloud Debugger which makes it easier to troubleshoot applications in production. Now you can simply pick a line of code, set a watchpoint and the debugger will return local variables and a full stack trace from the next request that executes that line on any replica of your service. There is zero setup time, no complex configurations and no performance impact noticeable to your users.

[Here's the blog post](http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.co.uk/2014/11/end-printf-debugging-in-cloud-with-Google-cloud-debugger-beta.html)

[Here's the info](https://cloud.google.com/tools/cloud-debugger)

Answer (score 1):

Not possible, you can only debug using the logs.

Comment: @Hugues describe your actual problem, i'm sure the community can help you.

Comment: You are right. I did include the problem and the solution. Was really a stupid mistake made by myself. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue. The problem was that one program was throwing an exception and I did not catch it properly. The code was

```
catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

On the development platform the exception was thrown at the console. The problem in production is that it does not appear in the GAE console. This has two very bad outcomes :

--> 1) The end user does not know that the transaction did not end successfully

--> 2) The administrator has no clue that a problem has occurred and no way to debug

==>

I have therefore replaced the code by

```
catch (Exception e) {
final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(InternalServiceImpl.class.getName());
log.severe("Problem while updating XXX record : " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
updatedRecord.setRPCResult(DB_PROBLEM); // This is specific to my application to notify the end user
}
```

I did modify the code relaunched the application and found out that the problem was a resource contention in a transaction.

Was really a stupid beginner mistake.